# Row level locking not working as expected in rails/mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, locking

I have following relation

```
parent has_many children 
child  belongs_to parent
```

And following code block

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do
  lock_acquired = true
  if child.parent.lock! and child.parent.status == 1
    child.parent.update_attributes(:status => 2)
  else
    lock_acquired = false
  end

  if lock_acquired
   # other code follows here
  end

end
```

The above code block is for making sure only one of the children is able to change the parent status at a time and hence the lock! method and the status check expression. But somehow its broken. Even though the parent status is changed to 2 by one of the children, another child is somehow able to pass through the if statement. There are multiple processes running of course but I thought lock would take care of that. Looks like lock is given back before the transaction block is completed.

May be lock works differently than I expected. Any insights would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Which storage engine are you using? Only InnoDB supports row-level locking -- I'm not sure whether `lock!` on a MyISAM table would fail silently or throw an error.

Comment: @Grantovich: storage engine is InnoDB.

Comment: Are you expecting that the `# other code follows here` section should not be executed if a second thread enters the transaction block? As it stands, only the `update_attributes` would be skipped (though if the "other code" contained anything that tried to update the parent, it would throw an error).

Comment: I should have been more clear on that. I've updated the code. Yes, I don't want second thread to execute     # other code follows here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why your updated code wouldn't work, but there is one odd thing about it: You're using `lock!` as though it returns a true/false value, but it can only ever return the model instance itself (if the lock is acquired) or raise an error (if acquiring the lock times out). This means `lock_acquired` will only be set to `false` if the lock actually *is* acquired, but the parent's status is not equal to `1`.

This code might behave more predictably:

```
child.parent.with_lock do
  if child.parent.status == 1
    child.parent.update_attributes(:status => 2)
  end

  # other code follows here
end
```

Note that `with_lock` behaves similarly to `lock!` -- either the block will be executed, or a lock timeout error will be thrown (after 50 seconds of waiting, under default MySQL settings).

Comment: "This means lock_acquired will only be set to false if the lock actually is acquired, but the parent's status is not equal to 1."

Yes, that is true. I should have used better naming than lock_acquired.  
One more thing, I've master/slave setup and using [makara](https://github.com/taskrabbit/makara). Looking at the split patterns, all the queries from a transaction go to primary (even the read queries). I'll remove the master/slave setup and use master only and see if the problem still exits. In that case, I'll try your solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. I would recommend changing your conditional logic for better clarity in any case -- using `lock!` as part of a conditional is misleading since it will always return the model instance, and never a false-ish value.